# Listview Custom Selector issue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i have a simple custom selector for my listview but i get an xml error any ideas why?
Errors:
unbound prefix (line 3)
not well formatted (invalid token) (line 5)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"
  <color android:color = "#FF8800"  />
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
  <shape>
     <gradient
      android:startColor="#E77A26"
        android:endColor="#E77A26"
        android:angle="270" />
  </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"
  <color android:color = "#FF8800" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Nadir B suggested, you didn't close your tag properly, unfortunately he suggested a wrong solution.

Item must wrap the color element(`<item ...> ... <color... /> </item>`) and not be a self closing element (eg `<item ... />`).
  You have made this mistake twice in the example you have given.  Ensure you notice both changes.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"
  <color android:color = "#FF8800"  />
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
  <shape>
     <gradient
      android:startColor="#E77A26"
        android:endColor="#E77A26"
        android:angle="270" />
  </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"
  <color android:color = "#FF8800" />
</selector>
```

Should be

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false">
  <color android:color = "#FF8800"  />
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
  <shape>
     <gradient
      android:startColor="#E77A26"
        android:endColor="#E77A26"
        android:angle="270" />
  </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false">
  <color android:color = "#FF8800" />
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

your not closing your xml tag

the problem is here

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"
```

> remove tab before

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

do like this
EDIT remove the space in xmlns like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
  <color android:color = "#FF8800"  />
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
  <shape>
     <gradient
      android:startColor="#E77A26"
        android:endColor="#E77A26"
        android:angle="270" />
  </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
  <color android:color = "#FF8800" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes one problem for not closing the xml tag
but i still get error

Unbound prefix (line 3)

Comment: thanks i still get this error after the edit , even if i remove all items tags and compile with an empty selector, i still get that issue

Comment: so it's coming from somewhere else

Comment: is it possible issue with my android SDK or Xamarin version?

Comment: possibly both of them